# .NetCore jquery No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: jquery, http-post, asp.net-core-2.0

If I try to send request to web api controller, I will get an error under a web browser:
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

Here is my jquery post request:

```
$.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:12345/api/xs/" + selectedId,
            data: JSON.stringify(anyObj),
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

and here is a (web api) controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class XSController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost("{id}")]
        [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
        //[DisableCors()]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(ushort id, [FromBody]AnyObjVM model)
        {
        }
    }
```

and startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
              builder =>
              {
                  builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                         .AllowCredentials()
                         ;
              });
    });
}

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) { app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); }

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Request header:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 166
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:12345
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
```

I tried to enable/disable CORS in startup.cs file and on controller method.
WebAPI is running on my local machine on IIS Express.
A site which calls web api is also on my local machine - I run the site manually (click on the site file), so that is why origin is set to null. Usually I'm able to call web api methods, **sometimes not**.
I also tried to run chrome with an option --disable-web-security (optionaly with --user-data-dir="d:/temp_chrome") but it didn't change anything.

How shall I resolve that issue?

Comment: Note that Chrome does not allow CORS requests on the `localhost` domain. Even if you were running on a valid domain you'd need to return CORS headers in the response from your Controller.